# How to expand a third menu and its sub menu items by default using javascript

Tags: javascript, menuitem, submenu, optionmenu, jmenuitem

Could any one please let me know how to expand the second submenu and its child items by default when I click on the main menu item. I have attached the screenshot for reference.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write a post that best enables the community to provide assistance.  Generally, it is expected you will include code showing what you've attempted so far or an [mcve] that clearly illustrates the problem.  Without even seeing what your markup structure look likes, there is probably not enough context in the question to provide useful answers.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.